# Drawing Beans from a bag

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop, arraylist

I have a program that draws beans from a bag and removes them on the following conditions. However my results don't seem to correlate at all, it seems as if the beans are not being remembered.

```
public class Prog477h {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> beans = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //make arrayList and add first 10 random beans
    Random addrand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int bean = addrand.nextInt(2);
        beans.add(bean);
    }
    //print title
    System.out.println("Beans\tBlack\tWhite\tLast");        
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) { //start for loop for 50 iterations
        int whites = countWhite(beans); //count the initial white
        int blacks = countBlack(beans); //count the initial black
        String last = getLast(beans); //get the last
        System.out.println(beans.size() + "\t" + blacks + "\t" + whites + "\t" + last + "\t"); //print row

        //draw two beans and remove them
        Random drawRand = new Random();
        int draw1 = drawRand.nextInt(beans.size());
        int beanDrawn1 = beans.get(draw1);
        beans.remove(beanDrawn1);
        int draw2 = drawRand.nextInt(beans.size());
        int beanDrawn2 = beans.get(draw2);
        beans.remove(beanDrawn2);

        //check the beans if they are 0 then they are white and if they are 1 they are black
        if (beanDrawn1 == 0 && beanDrawn2 == 0) { 
            beans.add(1); //both white, add a black
        } else if (beanDrawn1 == 1 && beanDrawn2 == 1) {
            beans.add(beanDrawn1); //both black add one back
        } else if (beanDrawn1 == 1 && beanDrawn2 == 0) {
            beans.add(beanDrawn2); //one black one white, add white back
        } else if (beanDrawn1 == 0 && beanDrawn2 == 1) {
            beans.add(beanDrawn1); //same as above
        }

        //add two random beans to offset for a +1 bean increase
        int bean = addrand.nextInt(2);
        beans.add(bean);
        bean = addrand.nextInt(2);
        beans.add(bean);
    }


}

//get the last
static String getLast(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    String display = "";
    int last = a.get(a.size() - 1);
    if (last == 0) {
        display += "White";
    } else {
        display += "Black";
    }
    return display;
}

//get the white
static int countWhite(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    int whites = 0;
    for (int i : a) { //go through loop and increase at 0s
        if (a.get(i) == 0) {
            whites++;
        }
    }
    return whites;
}

//get the black
static int countBlack(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    int blacks = 0;
    for (int i : a) { //go through loop and increase at 1s
        if (a.get(i) == 1) {
            blacks++;
        }
    }
    return blacks;
}
```

}

The output I get is.

Beans   Black   White   Last
10  6   4   Black
11  5   6   Black
12  0   12  White
13  13  0   White
14  14  0   White
15  11  4   White
16  12  4   White
17  0   17  White
18  13  5   White
19  0   19  White
20  0   20  White
21  8   13  White
22  7   15  White
23  15  8   White
24  14  10  Black
25  25  0   Black
26  0   26  Black
27  0   27  Black
28  14  14  White
29  15  14  White
30  14  16  Black
31  0   31  Black
32  0   32  Black
33  19  14  White
34  34  0   Black
35  35  0   White
36  36  0   Black
37  19  18  White
38  19  19  Black
39  0   39  White
40  40  0   White
41  20  21  Black
42  23  19  Black
43  43  0   White
44  44  0   White
45  0   45  White
46  21  25  White
47  22  25  Black
48  48  0   Black
49  0   49  Black
50  24  26  White
51  27  24  White
52  0   52  White
53  27  26  Black
54  28  26  Black
55  0   55  White
56  29  27  White
57  57  0   White
58  58  0   Black
59  32  27  Black
60  0   60  White

For example you can't change all the white beans to white on the last trial. Wtf is wrong please help.

Comment: *wtf is wrong* is not a question. [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576) Does your IDE have a debugger? What does it tell you when you step through the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with the way that you remove your beans.

```
int draw1 = drawRand.nextInt(beans.size());
int beanDrawn1 = beans.get(draw1);
beans.remove(beanDrawn1);
int draw2 = drawRand.nextInt(beans.size());
int beanDrawn2 = beans.get(draw2);
beans.remove(beanDrawn2);
```

Basically, what you are doing is getting a random index from the beans ArrayList and getting the result at that index, which is either 0 or 1.

The way that the beans.remove method works is that it removes the element at the INDEX that you put in to the method.

Therefore,

```
beans.remove(beanDrawn1);
```

will remove the first or second element of the array depending on if its white or black. Instead of removing a random index.

If you want to delete a random index, you would just skip the middle part and do

```
beans.remove(draw1);
```

I think this is how some beans are "not being remembered" as you mentioned. I haven't tested this, however, so try that change and see if it works.